# Number the result of views in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting data in from a controller and its printed through a loop. This is the example from the getting started guide. I want each row to have class in numbered in order like, class-1 class-2 etc.
Below is my code in view file.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.text %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(post) %> | </td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %> | </td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(post),
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

For example each row should be having classes in order like below when rendered:

```
  <tr class="class-1">
    <td>title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="class-2">
    <td>title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="class-3">
    <td>title</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I can't parse `each row to have class in numbered in order`.

Comment: I am basically starting to learn and this is a beginner question. I have added more details.

Comment: Use each_with_index? Increment a counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
<% classid = 0 %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= "<tr class=\"class-#{classid}\">" %>  
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.text %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(post) %> | </td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %> | </td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(post),
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
  <% classid +=1 %>
<% end %>
```

That said I'd be looking at presenter pattern, or a method on whatever class post is or better still if post is in the db, using it's id instead of sequential number.

Comment: Thanks, gives me more insight.

Comment: how about `each_with_index` instead

Comment: Why not indeed? It would be another way. Pretty new to Ruby, I just followed on from where the OP was at. This I would do with presenter anyway, and I'd use the id of post if available.